# why I am getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying convert date to string and getting following error..

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/BAB/POC/Slam.py", line 113, in <module>
    sheet0[col] = format_datecol(sheet0, col)
  File "C:/BAB/POC/Slam.py", line 85, in format_datecol
    newSheet[datecolumnname] = newSheet[datecolumnname].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d%b%Y'))
  File "C:\2020\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3848, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2327, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "C:/BAB/POC/Slam.py", line 85, in <lambda>
    newSheet[datecolumnname] = newSheet[datecolumnname].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d%b%Y'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime
```

'

The code follows here ...

```
for col in keycols0:
    if '_DT'.casefold() or 'DATE'.casefold() in col:
        sheet0[col] = format_datecol(sheet0, col)



def format_datecol(newSheet,datecolumnname):
    newSheet[datecolumnname] = newSheet[datecolumnname].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d%b%Y'))
    # newSheet[datecolumnname] = newSheet[datecolumnname].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%d%b%Y'))
    return newSheet[datecolumnname]
```

The issue is happening when I add multiple values in if condition with or getting above error ..fir the following code I am not getting the error

```
for col in keyColumnNames:
        if '_DT'.casefold() in col:
            tempSheet[col] = format_datecol(tempSheet, col)

def format_datecol(newSheet,datecolumnname):
    newSheet[datecolumnname] = newSheet[datecolumnname].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d%m%Y'))
    return newSheet[datecolumnname]
```

What would be the issue?

Comment: Did you try to print `newSheet[datecolumnname]`? Then you can see the type.

Comment: The second, comented option (`newSheet[datecolumnname].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%d%b%Y'))`) didn't work for you?

Comment: @MrNobody33 , no it didn't

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  In particular, we expect that you research the error message, trace the problem values, and post a question on what you don't understand *after* you've done that work.  See this lovely reference for [debugging help](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs).

Answer (score 0):

datecolumnname data is in `str` datatype and not in `datetime` datatype

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have `from datetime import datetime` in the beginning, and `x` is in the format of `'2020-06-28'`, try:

```
newSheet[datecolumnname] = newSheet[datecolumnname].apply(lambda x: datetime(*[int(d) for d in x.split('-')]).strftime('%d%b%Y'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply..
getting following error..

  lambda x: datetime(*[int(d) for d in x.split('-')]).strftime('%d%b%Y'))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'DP1401|18|VF|RM|HKD|025|B|NP|CB00000009'

Comment: My post assumes that `x` is in the format of `'2020-06-28'`, since you didn't specify in your question.

Comment: the following code works fine ..

for col in keycols0:
    if '_DT'.casefold() in col:
        sheet0[col] = format_datecol(sheet0, col)

def format_datecol(newSheet,datecolumnname):
    newSheet[datecolumnname] = newSheet[datecolumnname].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d%b%Y'))
      return newSheet[datecolumnname]

if I check for multiple values with or in if condition is failing..in this case I am using 'DATE', when i include DATE is throwing out the error